# ¿Cómo ejecutar código java en otro pc y se actualizar los datos de la app desde cualquier pc?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa en Java de asignación de casilleros el cual almacena los datos en un excel y los recorre para poder saber qué casilleros están ocupados y cuáles no. Quiero que este programa lo puedan abrir desde cualquier PC y que si se modifica un dato en alguno de los PCs que tenga el programa se modifique en todos. Entiendo que primeramente debería guardar la información en una base de datos como MySQL para que se pueda acceder a esta información desde cualquier PC, pero lo que no entiendo muy bien es qué hacer luego de hacer esto, cómo consigo que el programa corra en cualquier PC y demás. Cabe recalcar que soy nuevo en Java y por eso no entiendo el proceso de crear programas.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;

public class AsignacionCasilleros {
    static String[] casilleros = new String[50]; // Arreglo para representar el estado de cada casillero
    static JButton[] botonesCasilleros = new JButton[50]; // Arreglo de botones para los casilleros
    static String[][] datosCasilleros = new String[50][3]; // Arreglo para almacenar los datos de cada casillero: nombre, número de celular y descripción

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cargarEstadoCasilleros(); // Cargar el estado de los casilleros y los datos desde el archivo CSV

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Asignación de Casilleros");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 10)); // Cambiar el tamaño de la cuadrícula según sea necesario

        // Crear y agregar los botones numerados al panel
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            JButton botonCasillero = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1));
            botonesCasilleros[i] = botonCasillero;
            if (casilleros[i].equals("ocupado")) {
                botonCasillero.setBackground(Color.RED);
            } else {
                botonCasillero.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
            panel.add(botonCasillero);
            botonCasillero.addActionListener(new BotonCasilleroListener(i));
        }

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 400); // Modificar el tamaño de la ventana según tus necesidades
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Centrar la ventana en la pantalla

        // Guardar el estado de los casilleros y los datos en el archivo CSV al cerrar el programa
        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                guardarEstadoCasilleros();
            }
        });

        // Agregar el campo de búsqueda y el listener para búsqueda en tiempo real
        JTextField busquedaField = new JTextField();
        busquedaField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                buscarCasilleros(busquedaField.getText());
            }

            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                buscarCasilleros(busquedaField.getText());
            }

            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                buscarCasilleros(busquedaField.getText());
            }
        });
        frame.add(busquedaField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    static void cargarEstadoCasilleros() {
        try {
            File archivo = new File("estado_casilleros.csv");
            if (archivo.exists()) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
                String linea;
                int index = 0;
                while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] datos = linea.split(",");
                    casilleros[index] = datos[0];
                    if (datos.length >= 3) {
                        datosCasilleros[index][0] = datos[1];
                        datosCasilleros[index][1] = datos[2];
                        datosCasilleros[index][2] = datos[3];
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                br.close();
            } else {
                inicializarCasilleros();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void guardarEstadoCasilleros() {
        try {
            File archivo = new File("estado_casilleros.csv");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                bw.write(casilleros[i]);
                if (casilleros[i].equals("ocupado")) {
                    bw.write("," + datosCasilleros[i][0] + "," + datosCasilleros[i][1] + "," + datosCasilleros[i][2]);
                }
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void inicializarCasilleros() {
        for (int i = 0; i < casilleros.length; i++) {
            casilleros[i] = "disponible";
        }
    }

    static void asignarCasillero(int numCasillero) {
        if (casilleros[numCasillero].equals("ocupado")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Este casillero ya está ocupado");
        } else {
            JTextField nombreField = new JTextField();
            JTextField celularField = new JTextField();
            JTextField descripcionField = new JTextField();
            Object[] message = {
                    "Nombre:", nombreField,
                    "Número de celular:", celularField,
                    "Descripción:", descripcionField
            };

            int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Asignar Casillero " + (numCasillero + 1),
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                String nombre = nombreField.getText();
                String celular = celularField.getText();
                String descripcion = descripcionField.getText();
                casilleros[numCasillero] = "ocupado";
                datosCasilleros[numCasillero][0] = nombre;
                datosCasilleros[numCasillero][1] = celular;
                datosCasilleros[numCasillero][2] = descripcion;
                botonesCasilleros[numCasillero].setBackground(Color.RED);
                mostrarVentanaDatosCasillero(numCasillero);
            }
        }
    }

    static void desocuparCasillero(int numCasillero) {
        if (casilleros[numCasillero].equals("disponible")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Este casillero ya está desocupado");
        } else {
            casilleros[numCasillero] = "disponible";
            datosCasilleros[numCasillero][0] = "";
            datosCasilleros[numCasillero][1] = "";
            datosCasilleros[numCasillero][2] = "";
            botonesCasilleros[numCasillero].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            guardarEstadoCasilleros(); // Guardar el estado de los casilleros y los datos en el archivo CSV
            JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose(); // Cerrar la ventana de datos del casillero
        }
    }

    static void mostrarVentanaDatosCasillero(int numCasillero) {
        String nombre = datosCasilleros[numCasillero][0];
        String celular = datosCasilleros[numCasillero][1];
        String descripcion = datosCasilleros[numCasillero][2];
        JButton liberarCasilleroButton = new JButton("Liberar Casillero");

        liberarCasilleroButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                desocuparCasillero(numCasillero);
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Nombre: " + nombre));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Número de celular: " + celular));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Descripción: " + descripcion));
        panel.add(liberarCasilleroButton);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Datos Casillero " + (numCasillero + 1));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static void buscarCasilleros(String palabraBusqueda) {
    if (palabraBusqueda.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if (casilleros[i].equals("ocupado")) {
                botonesCasilleros[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
            } else {
                botonesCasilleros[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if (casilleros[i].equals("ocupado")) {
                if (datosCasilleros[i][0].toLowerCase().contains(palabraBusqueda.toLowerCase()) ||
                        datosCasilleros[i][1].toLowerCase().contains(palabraBusqueda.toLowerCase()) ||
                        datosCasilleros[i][2].toLowerCase().contains(palabraBusqueda.toLowerCase())) {
                    botonesCasilleros[i].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                } else {
                    botonesCasilleros[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            } else {
                botonesCasilleros[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    }
}


    static class BotonCasilleroListener implements ActionListener {
        int numCasillero;

        public BotonCasilleroListener(int numCasillero) {
            this.numCasillero = numCasillero;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (casilleros[numCasillero].equals("disponible")) {
                asignarCasillero(numCasillero);
            } else {
                mostrarVentanaDatosCasillero(numCasillero);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Para que corra en cualquier pc, debes instalar todo lo necesario en cada pc. Y luego, la base de datos debe estar en la misma red, asi podes acceder desde cualquiera de las pc...

Comment: Hola Juan, cualquier PC que tenga instalada la versión mínima requerida por tu aplicación del JRE (o JVM), la correrá sin problemas.